# Google Autocomplete suggestion out of place in angular

Tags: angular, google-maps, dialog

I am using google autocomplete in angular mat-dialog.

I added the search field inside the mat-dialog.

When i search something, the suggestion is automatically on top or over the search bar

[image]

Any idea on how do i solve it or guide me.? Do take note that this is a mat dialog.
Where have i done wrong.
Below are my codes

app.html

```
<div *ngIf="!passAddressCheck">
    <p class="montserratSemiBold fontSize22px">Seach of an address</p>
    <div class="marginBottom30px marginTop30px">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="off" type="text" class="form-control" #search [formControl]="searchControl">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p *ngIf="showErrorAddress" class="errorColor fontSize14px montserratRegular marginBottom30px">Sorry we do not deliver to you address at this moment</p>
  </div>
```

app.component.ts

```
searchControl: FormControl;

this.searchControl = new FormControl();


@ViewChild('search', {static: false})
public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      const autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        componentRestrictions: {country: 'my'}
      });

      autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {

          const place: google.maps.places.PlaceResult = autocomplete.getPlace();

          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }

          this.latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
          this.longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
          this.zoom = 12;

        });
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: You must use the directives mat-dialog-title, mat-dialog-content in your dialog HTML in order to have each element properly, your issue seems to be related to CSS. Try to replicate it on stackblitz in order to help you.

Comment: That doesnt seems to be the problem. I just tried it out.
But i did figure something out and that is the suggestion box is following the scroll of the page behind the dialog. so when i scroll higher and press the dialog button, the suggestion will show right just below the input. 
But when i scroll lower, the suggestion goes on top of the screen.

Comment: Having the same Problem... Any solution found?

Comment: My solution is to use primeng dialog